# How do I get all unique values from a list of strings that each contain a collection of attributes in R?

Tags: r, stringr

This is for one of my classes, I got a data frame to analyse and get some statistical conclusions, basically, one of the variables is composed by strings that look something like this:

`{obj1,"obj2",obj3,"obj4",obj5,"obj6",obj7,obj8,obj9,"obj10","obj11","obj12",obj13}`

The objects between "" contain spaces.

I am trying to make a list of all of these appended and then filter it to remove all {,"\} (some contain backslashes as well).

*edited here, didn't know i had to use double backslashes here as well

I tried some different methods that I have found online, and that part of my r code looks like this right now:

```
#analyzing amenities
amm_ord = c(df1$amenities)
unique (amm_ord)
k = c()
for (elements in amm_ord){
  
  #for (element in elements) {k = append(k,unlist(element))
  #for (element in elements) {k = c( k , element )
  for (element in elements){
    k1 = strsplit(element, regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}' ,))
    k = c (k , k1)
    }
} 
uni_amm = unique(k)

print(uni_amm)

#k1 = strsplit(amm_ord , '\\",\\"  ,\\"  "{  ')
my_string <- "{  ,\",\",\",  \",  \"}"
k1 = strsplit(amm_ord , my_string)
k1 = strsplit(amm_ord , regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}'))
k1 = str_extract(k , regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}'))
#amm_ord = strsplit(k1 , '\\",')
#k1 = strsplit(amm_ord , '"\\",\\""\\"')
unique(k1)
unique(amm_ord)
```

I keep getting errors and can't get regexpr to work, how would you do it?

My latest idea was this:

```
for (elements in amm_ord){
  
  for (element in elements){
    k1 = strsplit(element, regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}' ,[idk what to put here]))
    k = c (k , k1)
    }
}
```

these are my outputs:

```
Error in check_lengths(string, pattern) : 
  argument "pattern" is missing, with no default
>     k1 = str_extract(element, ('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}'))
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL, context=`“{  ,\”  \”,\”  \”,  \”}`)
>     k1 = str_extract(element, regex('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}'))
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
  Error in {min,max} interval. (U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL, context=`“{  ,\”  \”,\”  \”,  \”}`)
>     k1 = str_extract(element, regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}'))
Error in is.factor(text) : argument "text" is missing, with no default
>     k1 = strsplit(element, regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}'))
Error in is.factor(text) : argument "text" is missing, with no default
>     k1 = strsplit(element, regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}' , txt))
Error in is.factor(text) : object 'txt' not found
>     k1 = strsplit(element, regexpr('“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}' , element))
Error in regexpr("“{  ,\\”  \\”,\\”  \\”,  \\”}", element) : 
  invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
>
```

Comment: So what's the desired output for this sample input? Are you only trying to keep values inside of quotes? Do you know why the data is formatted this way? If it's some kind of known data format, there may already exist a parser for it. It almost looks JSON like but I can't tell how different your real data might be from this example.

Comment: hi, just saw this. I am working with a csv file, i am hoping to get a list of all unique objects that can be found in those lists. That's my end goal.

Comment: Can you post a better piece of example data that matches what you’re looking at? It seems that your original example (obj1 etc) is placeholder. A few rows of the dataframe would be best, e.g. `dput(head(iris))` with unneeded columns removed. If not, some example entries in amm_ord.